# How to add a class/id for a specific page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need a page that changes languages, depending on the URL. I'd like to add a class to an element when the URL contains `en`. For instance, `example.com/en` should show the page in English, while `example.com` shows the same page in Spanish.

How can I add or change a class in a div when I'm in example.com (Default language) and example.com/en (secondary language)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to include things you've tried, other posts you've read, code examples, and anything else that is relevant to your question. It helps us help you. I edited your answer to clean up the English, and make it more easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

`get_locale()` gets the current language used on a page e.g. en_GB. See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_locale) for more details.

`<div id="flag" class="<?php echo get_locale();?>">`

Comment: And if i just want to do it by page, not location?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Dassin Sorry I am not sure what you mean.